# shell_exec : скрипт не запускается

Tags: linux, скрипт

```html
shell_exec("sudo -u www-data cd /home/web/*****/www/server ; 
nohup node w.js >phplog.txt 2>&1 & ");
```

Этот код находится в файле /start.php. Из браузера если обратится на прямую к нему - скрипт w.js запускается.
Однако, если сделать(include) этого файла (/start.php) в другой - то процесс w.js не запускается. $output ничего не возвращает. Изменения типа >/dev/null 2>&1 & приводят только к кратковременному запуску процесса, позже он останавливается. В чем проблема?

Comment: просто к слову: команда `sudo -u www-data cd каталог` скорее всего завершается ошибкой — ведь вряд ли в вашей системе есть **программа** `cd`. да и сам вызов программы `sudo` скорее всего лишён смысла — ведь процесс и так наверняка исполняется от имени пользователя `www-data`

Comment: Спасибо. Главная проблема была - доступ/разрешение файла(из разных мест скрипт запускался и связанные с ним файлы.) Однако  проблема продолжилась - из-за этого sudo -u www-data - действительно скрипт запускался и сразу уничтожался. То есть две проблемы были